# log2console / How to open exported csv file in log2console?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am trying to analyze the log by sending the project log to Udp using the Nlog library to log2console and saving it as a CSV file.

I try to this.

1. Project used Nlog Libray
2. Project Send to Log2Console (UDP)
3. Log2Console export Csv file.
4. Open Csv File.

I had "3.Log2Console export Csv file."
but I cant "4.open Csv File"

How to Open to Csv File?
I don't know what setting I am missing.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

i can did it.

1. exe Log2Console
2. Settings / Columns / CSV File Header Column Settings/ Add Array information
3. Open Log File / select CSV file.
4. add Reciver / CSV Log File / modifty Configuration. "Read Header From File" = True
5. Field List Count Check.
6. OK

log2Console "open CSV file" have error.

If open CSV file. Time is get Wrong time. so you must edit source code.

I dont know. how to Settings logSource, localSource.

How to send client sourcceDir information?